# Wrap mid-word in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there a way to wrap code such that when wrapping is needed, the first line always shows enough characters to take up the full width of the editor, rather than moving some of the characters to the next line based on word boundaries?  For instance, if wrapping is currently applied like this:

```
-------------------------------------------+
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur    |
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     |
incididunt ut labore                       |
-------------------------------------------+
```

how can I instead have it applied like this?:

```
-------------------------------------------+
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adi|
piscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidid|
unt ut labore                              |
-------------------------------------------+
```

As for why I want to do this, I find that it helps me more quickly identify **when** a line is wrapped.

Comment: Ugh, I want this so bad.